# Windows has triggered a breakpoint due to corruption in heap or dlls loaded

Tags: c#, c++

I have a **C++** file with some exported functions which I am calling in C#. One of the functions is this:

```
char segexpc[MAX_SEG_LEN];

extern "C" QUERYSEGMENTATION_API char* fnsegc2Exported()
{
    return segexpc2;
}
```

Somewhere in the program, I am also doing this thing:

```
if(cr1==1)
{
strcpy(segexpc, seg);
}
```

In my **C#** program, I am invoking the above by the followign way:

```
[DllImport("QuerySegmentation.dll", EntryPoint = "fnsegcExported", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern StringBuilder fnsegcExported();
```

this.stringbuildervar = fnsegcExported();

Previously, I was not getting any error, but now suddenly I have started getting this error, when I debug  in visual studio.

```
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in SampleAppGUI.exe.
This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in SampleAppGUI.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.
This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while SampleAppGUI.exe has focus.
```

This error appears only at the end just before it has to display the window. I have not pressed any F12 key key and neither is any breakpoint set here, but I am not sure why the error is occuring and breaking at this point.  `this.stringbuildervar = fnsegcExported();`
When I press on continue, the window appears with the correct output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would happen if you changed your external declaration from

```
[DllImport("QuerySegmentation.dll", EntryPoint = "fnsegcExported", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern StringBuilder fnsegcExported();
```

to

```
[DllImport("QuerySegmentation.dll", EntryPoint = "fnsegcExported", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern string fnsegcExported();
```

And then called it in the following way:

```
this.stringbuildervar = new StringBuilder(fnsegcExported());
```

`string` seems the more appropriate type. Or better yet use the `Marshal` class to marshal your unmanaged char* return into a managed string.

```
[DllImport("QuerySegmentation.dll", EntryPoint = "fnsegcExported", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern IntPtr fnsegcExported();

string managedStr = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(fnsegcExported);
this.stringbuildervar = new StringBuilder(managedStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you see the error on this line is that it is the last stack frame for which you have debug information.

Fortunately, in your case, there is very little code on the C++ side.  Make sure that `segexpc` contains a zero terminated string.

I suspect that because the default capacity of the string builder is 16, you may not be able to return longer strings in this fashion.  Maybe you want to return just strings.

I also wonder whether your C++ string has to be non-Unicode.  That will hurt performance upon every conversion.

Comment: @jarika: I am not fully acquainted with C++ but I was wondering if strcpy copies until `\0`. If not is there any function in C++, which automatically copies and makes the destination string as null terminated string as well?

Comment: strcpy will add the null-terminator for you (\0)
`Copies the C string pointed by source into the array pointed by destination, including the terminating null character`